# Passing First argument variable to a function in node/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api, slack

I am working on a Javascript code snippet (node.js) where I have code like : 
Defined at Global level:

```
var map = {
    "k1": "v1",
    "k2": "v2",
    "k3": "v3"
};

controller.hears('k2', function (obj1, obj2) {
     //var arg = arguments[0] + " --";
     yet_another_func(map['k2'], obj1, obj2);
});
```

Since I can not pass a variable in controller, I am going to pass an array there in the format :

```
    controller.hears('k1|k2|k3', function (obj1, obj2) {
```

Now, I want to get the associated value of the field (k1/k2/k3) from the map variable without hardcoding. I have tried using arguments **arguments[0]** that doesn't seems to be working. In bash I remember $1 used to be the first argument.

Is there similar approach I can use for this case as well ?

e.g. of controller https://github.com/slackhq/easy-peasy-bot/blob/master/index.js#L73 Its a #slack library

Comment: what lib is that? what does controller.hears? what arguments are passed to the callback-function?

Comment: `arguments[0]` does indeed return the first argument passed to the function. But I guess that's not whats you are after. Unfortunately I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please provide a complete example with expected input and output. See [mcve].

Comment: @Thomas updated ! its a slack library

Comment: What are the  values of `obj1` and `obj2`? Are you looking for `map[obj1]` or `map[obj2]`?

Comment: I guess looking at the documentation should help: https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/b96ef7a06618c1f0d63dc5a7bfef34c8817641c2/readme.md#matching-patterns-and-keywords-with-hears

Comment: @FelixKling obj1 and obj2 are irrelevant. Just passing them along.

Comment: also I guess  (.*) may work for me. Will try that out.

Comment: @FelixKling it worked. Can you answer it so I can mark it as an answer :)